# Is there a way to get JButtons on a new line, JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

I am making a basic soundboard in java and i want it so that the every 2 buttons are on a different line like:

```
(button) (button)
(button) (button)
```

This is my code as of now

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JButton one = new JButton(sound1);
JButton two = new JButton(sound2);
JButton three = new JButton(sound3);
JButton four = new JButton(sound4);
JButton five = new JButton(sound5);

p.add(one);
p.add(two);
p.add(three);
p.add(four);
p.add(five);

int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Test", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, -1);
```

What would be the easiest way to do it? If i have to switch to a JFrame let me know i wont mind if that is the only option.

Comment: Another option is to build a custom [`JDialog`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

Comment: If you have used the panel that's great!
Just set the desired layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) in your `JPanel`:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

First argument is the number of rows, second one is the number of columns. If you specify number of rows as 0 you are telling the layout manager that you just want to have two columns and don't know how many rows you're going to need - the rows will be created dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the GridLayout, it presents components in a table. like below, 3 is the number of rows, 2 is the number of columns.

```
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

    p.add(one);
    p.add(two);
    p.add(three);
    p.add(four);
    p.add(five);
```